# How to overlap 2 different Y axis plot using OverLay

Tags: plotting, overlay

I want to plot the following image using **ListPlot** [taking the points from get data graph]

[image]

and I used the command **OverLay** along with **ImagePadding ip = {{85, 65}, {125, 0.16}} and ImageSize-> 500** but I have got this:

[image]
where, large blue points are the same as those are shown in the above graph [Data].The small dark blue points represents the yellow line in the above graph. But somehow those large blue points have been shifted above. I have taken those points several times to check whether there is any mistake or not but for all the cases it gives the similar result.

Would you kindly suggest me how I can fix this problem such that the small blue points will pass in between the Large blue points as shown in the original figure.

Comment: please share your data and the code you used for us to be able to help more meaningfully. Generally, I would think that `Show` would work better to combine plots than Overlay though.

Comment: You should switch off the unused frame ticks at left and right axis of corresponding layers. The same is true for frame labels. It is evident..

Comment: Sir, I have tried to plot the above using the command Show but it gives nothing as these 2 Y axis values are very much different from each other. Probably, Show option gives correct result where the Y axis values are not too different from each other, which is not maintained here.